# How to ignore/disable all USB HID devices except a certain one using udev rules?

Tags: linux, usb, udev, usb-device

I would like to ignore/disable all USB HID devices except a certain one, using udev rule(s). I have the `idVendor` and `idProduct` attributes of the USB HID device I want to allow.

I am able to disable all USB HID devices using:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usbhid", ACTION=="add", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

I got this from [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786343/prevent-usbhid-from-autoloading-when-usb-hid-device-is-plugged-in). But, this prevents the one USB HID device I want to allow from being used as well.

I have attempted to create a solution, based on this [Allow only known USB devices](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Allow_only_known_usb_devices) page from the Gentoo wiki. But, no dice.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usbhid", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTR{idProduct}=="YYYY", ATTR{authorized}="1", GOTO="usb_hid_end"

# Disable all other USB HID devices.
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", DRIVERS=="usbhid", ACTION=="add", ATTR{authorized}="0"

LABEL="usb_hid_end"
```

How can I ignore/disable all USB HID devices except a certain one, using it's `idVendor` and `idProduct` attributes?